# Odd behavior with DefaultCommandPrefix and NestedModules

Tags: powershell

I created a module, that imports nested modules and it doesn't work right if I set the default command prefix.

One of the recommendations I found on the web was to make the module easier to maintain by creating new folders and separate files for the modules. 
So I have

- Module.psm1
- Common\Common.psm1
- `Get-Data`
- Company\Company.psm1
- `Get-Company`

I am also trying to use the *Default Command Prefix* option as well. When I add that, and then try and use the module it breaks.

Without Command prefix, I'm able to call `get-company`, which is able to call get-data and everything is happen.

When I ADD command prefix, I can no longer call `Get-Data`. If I move the Function `Get-Company` to the Module file then it is able to call `Get-Data`.

Am I doing something wrong here, is this an odd bug, is this expected behavior, Details on the Default Command Prefix are very sparse here:[How to Write a PowerShell Module Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest)

Comment: Well, I "solved" this this month; nearly 2 years later. Taking a combination of some other people's suggestions in other articles. I create a Public/ folder with all the functions that I want exposed in the PSM file and then Get-ChildItem -Recurse Public/ and Get-Content | out-file -append module.psm1 .